# Style Chakra UI FormControl and label at application theme level

Tags: reactjs, themes, styled-components, chakra-ui, theme-ui

Have been using Chakra for a while but I can not get my head around styling all my components, in this case, `FormControl` at a global level with the theme file.

For example if i want to add margin bottom to my `FormControl` and `FormLabel` elements I would add the components object to the theme file like so:

```
  components: {
    Form: {
      parts: ['control', 'label', 'errorMessage'],
      baseStyle: {
        control: {
          marginBottom: '2rem',
        },
        label: {
          marginBottom: '3rem',
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

But this has no effect on the base style of the rendered `FormControl` or `FormLabel`.

Could someone please help me with what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
import type { ComponentStyleConfig } from '@chakra-ui/theme';
import { extendTheme } from '@chakra-ui/react'


const Form: ComponentStyleConfig = {
  // The styles all button have in common
  parts: ['container'],
  baseStyle: {
    /// The container styles the FormControl
    container: {
      marginY: '20px'
    }
  },
}

const theme = extendTheme({
  components: {
    Form,
  },
})
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I get a TypeScript error with the `Form` line because it does not exist within `ComponentStyleConfig`. were you able to resolve that?

Answer (score 2):

```
export const formStyles = {
  parts: ['container', 'requiredIndicator', 'helperText'],
  baseStyle: {
    container: {
      label: {
        fontSize: '14px',
        fontWeight: 'bold',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Import it into your component styles

```
components: {
  Form: formStyles,
}
```

Comment: this worked! can you please attach the source/reference?

Answer (score 1):

Having looked through the source code a bit more there is no parts array to FormControl as it is a Context rather than a component. Therefore, it cannot be styled!